# Different background-color for left and right half of div

Tags: html, css, background, center

I have a centered div layout. The left side of the div in the background should be white and the right side should be green. Both should extend to infinity.

I think it should be quite simple but I just don't get it right now. Any easy solution?
Thank you!

```
-----------------------------------------------------
(div 1)     __________________________ 
           |(div 2)         |         |
           |                |         |
           |                |         |
<- white   |     white      |  green  |   green  ->
           |                |         |
           |                |         |
           |________________|_________|

------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You might get some further ideas if you ask on doctype.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a background image with the two colors to the outer div and allow the browser to scale it (instead of tiling it).

Each color should fill exactly 50% of the width of the image to make sure the colors will never leak on either side.

Maybe even position the image absolutely behind the inner div.

For ideas how to stretch the image, see this question: [CSS Background Repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277330/css-background-repeat)

Comment: Thank you, works out pretty cool! Didn't even know you can stretch bg-images.

Answer (score 16):

Use the `::after` and `::before` psuedo elements. That way you can even get three colors and do the Italian flag!

```
div {
    height:300px;
    width:100%;
    outline:thin solid black;
    position:relative;
    background:white;
}
div::after, div::before {
    height:300px;
    content:' ';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 33%;
}
div::after {
    right: 0;
    background-color: red;
}
div::before {
    left: 0;
    background-color: green;
}
```

**Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g8p9pn1v/**

And its results: [image]

Answer (score 4):

How about create two divs bg-left and bg-right, with a position absolute inside a full width container. Since they are absolutely positioned, you can then layer content on top of them. So for example, using bootstrap markup:

```
<div class="fullwidth">
    <div class="bg-left"></div>
    <div class="bg-right"></div>    

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                Insert left side content here...
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                Insert right side content here...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then your css:

```
.fullwidth {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
 }
.bg-left {
    background: #000; 
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
}
.bg-right {
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #ddd; 
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way in 2021:

```
.container {
  background: linear-gradient(
    to right, 
    red 0%, 
    red 50%, 
    black 50%, 
    black  100%
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks @Oleg! before I found your answer, I thought to myself, if I can't find an easy way, I'll just go with a gradient. duh!

Answer (score 1):

You could have two divs on the outside, and then have one of your divs in each. Right-align and left-align respectively. Like so:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
(div)                       | (div)
           _________________|_________ 
           |(div)           |  (div)  |
           |                |         |
           |                |         |
<- white   |     white      |  green  |   green  ->
           |                |         |
           |                |         |
           |________________|_________|
                            |
------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: But this only works if the line between the two outer divs is exactly at 50% of the screen (which it is not in my layout)?

Answer (score 0):

I'd put inside that div two other divs and give them the appropriate sizes and backgound colors

Comment: The centered div2 is already inside that other div1. It is centered by using margin:auto. I don't think I can put two other divs inside there?

Comment: sure you can.  you will need to add the two more divs or deal with a repeating background image that does the color change for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Gradient**. This is a website where you can get the cross-browser code of what you need.

http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

It may be a little confusing to use at the begining but I find it a very powerfull tool.

Regards!